# What is the best way to inform a UITableViewCell that the tableview is scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I'm currently posting a NSNotification that the cell is listening for if the tableview starts scrolling and when it stops scrolling. Is this the right/most efficient approach?

*** UPDATE***

Apparently this wasn't clear enough. I'm not trying to inform the tableview that it's scrolling.
I'm using this:

```
- (void )scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // How should I tell all of my tableview cells that we scrolled.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"scrolled" object:self];

}
```

And then when the cell is created -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseVideo:)    name:@"scrolled" object:nil];
```

And then posting a notification that each allocated cell is listening for.
Is this the best approach?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve with it? Maybe there is another way?

Comment: @Fogmeister I want to pause a avplayer inside a uitableviewcell when then table begins to scroll.

Comment: @Fogmeister - each cell has it's own avplayer.

Comment: Not my down vote BTW.

Comment: Yes, that's a fine approach.

Comment: so for any pixel scrolled you want a notification and stop all videos?

Comment: show us th gcd code, as there might be dragons.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - showing GCD code. Pretty straight forward, I think. Pausing the videos helps performance, but something is still causing scroll stickiness.

Comment: ?? there is not a single line gcd code.

Comment: @vikingosegundo  - sorry, tired. I meant Notification Center.

Comment: @vikingosegundo but thanks - that helped me find the dragons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for scrolling performance it is better to use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, because it is called once. And in this handler you can just iterate through visible cells and stop player in each of them.

Comment: That was it. I'm still using - (void )scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *)scrollView, but I was posting a Notification each pixel, basically! The solution was to set a var isScrolling to TRUE and only post a notification when isScrolling changes from FALSE to TRUE.

Comment: @kevin btw, isScrolling already presented in UIScrollView since v1

Answer (score 2):

A UITableView inherits from UIScrollView.  So, there are delegate methods on the UIScrollView which is contained inside the TableView. You should adapt those methods inside your controller.

UPDATED:

Try adapting this:

```
tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: This will work but only for the visible cells. The way a tableview queues cells means that rows outside of the view won't have a cell referenced to it. Might be a problem if you need to pause the AVPlayers on them? Maybe.

Comment: @Fogmeister But no cell = no AVPlayer. No problem.